# Blender 2.9 Sever relationship between Grease Pencil and animation

Tags: grease-pencil

I want to use the grease pencil but I do not want it to create keyframes or do any animation.  How is this done? are grease pencil layers "hard wired" to be keyframes ?

Comment: What are you looking to achieve? Yes a drawing in GP will be a keyframe but if you only draw 1 frame it wont animate in any way if that's what you're asking? It'll remain static.

Comment: Yes right now I only want to discover a way to do concept models in 3d for unique lighting.  the pen tablet maskes grease pencil really cool.  There is confusion about why i start a white background 2d when really it allows for 3d.  Grease Pencil might have industry meaning that I am unaware of.